# Why is my 'length' changed by my computer?

Tags: c

My `length` just changed for no reason.

Here is the code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

void HeapAdjust(int *a,int s,int length);
void swap(int *a,int m,int n);

int main(){
    int a[] = {99,19,2,98,103,3,9,20,78,201,88,9,23,46,77,59,67,69,75,38};

    /* 
      bug here 
    */
    int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    for(int i=length/2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        HeapAdjust(a,i,length);
    }

    for(int i=length;i>0;i--)
    {
        swap(a,0,i-1);
        HeapAdjust(a,0,i-2);
    }

    /* Show the result of Heap_sort */
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
}

void HeapAdjust(int *a,int s,int length)
{
    int temp = a[s];
    for(int j=s*2;j<=length;j*=2)
    {
        if(j<length&&a[j+1]>a[j])
            j++;
        if(temp>=a[j])
            break;
        a[s] = a[j];
        s = j;
    }
    a[s] = temp;
}

void swap(int *a,int m,int n)
{
    int temp = a[m];
    a[m] = a[n];
    a[n] = temp;
}
```

I don't have any pointer or reference of the `length`. I found that it'll change when I don't get it a `const`. The `length` will strangely change to 3, but it should be 10. I don't get it.

[image]

Comment: Not having looked too closely at your code, are you writing outside the bounds of your array? I see `j<=length` which is usually wrong when `j` is an index and `length` is an array length.

Comment: Where is it changing? If you know it changes, surely you can show us where did you print length in the code that it changes.

Comment: @MMZK1526 It's on the screenshot, in the Locals window.

Comment: Add a variable watch in your debugger for `a` and see if it's changing.

Comment: It's not related to your bug, but you should maybe use `const int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);`, which would allow some optimizations. Incidentally, it would *probably* also make the bug you have here to manifest in a different way,

Comment: @hyde *"I found that it'll change when I don't get it a `const`"*

Comment: @ Thomas Jager  I posted the picture,right under my code,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical error in C coding: You write beyond the size of array (e.g. on element below 0 or greater equal array size).
Proof: int a[21] will work.
But then define: int length = 20;

Here, I found this:

```
for(int i=length;i>0;i--)
{
    swap(a,0,i-1);
    HeapAdjust(a,0,i-2);
}
```

which means i can be 1,
and thus last argument in HeapAdjust will be -1.

Some additional "printf" commands show that array elements beyond 19 are accessed, which is wrong anyway - and which can lead to some undefined behaviour.

```
void HeapAdjust(int *a,int s,int length)
{
    int temp = a[s];
    for(int j=s*2;j<=length;j*=2)
    {
        printf("redfined a %i %i\n",j+1,j);
        if(j<length && a[j+1]>a[j]){
            j++;}
            printf("redfined b %i %i\n",s,j);
        if(temp>=a[j])
            break;
            
        a[s] = a[j];
        s = j;
    }
    printf("redfined c %i\n",s);
    a[s] = temp;
}

void swap(int *a,int m,int n)
{
    printf("redfined d %i\n",m);
    printf("redfined e %i\n",n);  
    int temp = a[m];
    a[m] = a[n];
    a[n] = temp;
}


./a.out
redfined a 21 20
redfined b 10 20
redfined c 10
redfined a 19 18
redfined b 9 18
redfined c 9
redfined a 17 16
redfined b 8 17
redfined c 8
redfined a 15 14
redfined b 7 14
redfined c 14
redfined a 13 12
redfined b 6 13
redfined c 13
redfined a 11 10
redfined b 5 10
redfined a 21 20
redfined b 10 20
```

Suggestion:
Rewrite the code and check to access elements only between 0 and 19 (for this example of array length = 20). Personal suggestion: Try to make the code clearer for human reading for correct understanding. It does not have to be as short as possible (to be correct).

Comment: Thanks U2y for feedback. A further idea is to print the array a after each step, and see if the code works as expected, like to "printf" which step was performed and the result of this step. (Because it also possible that a sorting algorithm can recover from "a few" wrong steps.)

Comment: Really appreciate it,thks for advice!

Comment: By the way,it is a out_of_range problem,but i'm still curious about why my `length` getting to be 3,isn‘ it weird?

Comment: @U2y that depends on the memory layout. If `length` happens to be located just after your array, your out-of-bounds access can destroy the value of `length`.

Comment: @ Gerhardh thks for answering,got it!

Answer (score 0):

### Just found the bug,its the function **HeapAdjust**.

```
void HeapAdjust(int *a,int s,int length)
{
    int temp = a[s];
    for(int j=s*2;j<=length;j*=2)
    {
        if(j<length&&a[j+1]>a[j])
            j++;
        if(temp>=a[j])
            break;
        a[s] = a[j];
        s = j;
    }
    a[s] = temp;
}
```

###### when `i` is 5,which means `s` is 5 here,it will finally make `s` be 20.yeah,just above length,and I believe it is the result of bug.

just make `>=` be `>`,length went well.

I'm new at programming,if there is any other advice for coding,plz just do it.

Comment: Sorry, but i do not get it. Where is the new HeapAdjust any different to the original version?

Comment: @sidcoder look the 4th row,if u changed the `>=` to `>`,it will be solved.

Comment: @sidcoder  u make `s` be 5,and follow the loop,you'll see `s` will finally be 20,which is above the length of my arr.

Comment: In the 4th row is neither `>` nor `>=` There is only `<=`. Changing this to `<` would still allow illegal accesses. If `j==length-1` you will access `a[j+1]` which is illegal. And you will do `j++` and lateron `a[s]=a[j]` again with illegal index. This is only reading so far, but with `s=j;` you will finally do `a[s]=temp` where you can access one beyond the array.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes,ur right,to many out of range,I have corrected it yet.thks.

Comment: I hope, it became clear "Why is my 'length' changed by my computer?". "The computer" changed the length, because the code which you showed writes outside the array - and thus overwrites 'length' (in this particular case). That is already the answer. Generally, the algorithm is not correct, if array elements outside the array size are accessed. No matter, if the code still works (in a particular case) - and it needs to be corrected. Then, for correct algorithm and coding of Heapsort, please refer to internet resources. (Note: The question here, at SO, is not about Heapsort).